# Is the Upper Banach density always zero with respect to some sequence of Finite subset

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, ergodic-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, ramsey-theory

The following question came to me while reading the paper '[Density in Arbitrary Semigroups](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266702090_Density_in_Arbitrary_Semigroups)' by Hindman and Strauss.

**Question:** Given an infinite subset $A$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $A^c$ is also infinite, does there exists a sequence $\mathcal{F}=\{F_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ so that the Upper Banach density of $A$, i.e., $d_{\mathcal{F}}^*(A)=0 \,?$,

where $d_{\mathcal{F}}^*(A):=\sup\{\alpha:\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\exists \, n_0\geq n \text{ and } x\in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that } |A\cap (F_{n_0}+x)|\geq \alpha |F_{n_0}|\}$.

Even if the answer is negative in general, is it true for some particular infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}\,?$

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: No: consider the set $A=\mathbb N\setminus\{2^n:n\in\omega\}$.

Comment: @TarasBanakh What do you mean by $\omega$?

Comment: $\omega$ is the set of non-negative integers and $\mathbb N:=\omega\setminus\{0\}$ is the set of positive integers.

Comment: Sets $A\subset\mathbb N$ such that $d^*_\mathcal F(A)=0$ for every Folner sequence $\mathcal F$ are called *absolute null set*, see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/45885323_Completeness_of_translation-invariant_ideals_in_groups

Comment: It seems that you gave incorect definition of the upper Banach density. The sequence $\mathcal F$ cannot be arbitrary (otherwise every infinite subset will have upper Banach density 1). The sequence $\mathcal F$ should satisfy the Folner condition: for every $x\in \mathbb N$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|F_n\triangle (F_n+x)|}{|F_n|}=0$.

Comment: My question is depending on $A$, can we choose a sequence $\mathcal{F}=\{F_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$(not necessarily Folner!) so that $d_{\mathcal{F}}^*(A)=0\,?$. $\mathcal{F}$ is not arbitrary in the definition of Upper Banach density.

Comment: Yes! You are right. Every infinite subset is of Upper Banach density 1 with respect to $\textbf{some}$ sequence $\mathcal{F}$. But my question is actually the opposite, as said before.

Comment: Then the set $A=\mathbb N\setminus\{2^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a counterexample. For every sequence $\mathcal F$ the set $A$ has $d^*_\mathcal F(A)=1$.

Comment: Do you mind sharing how to prove that $d_{\mathcal{F}}^*(A)=1$ for any Folner sequence $\mathcal{F}$, where $A$ is as given by you ?

Comment: Use the fact that the distance between the neighbor elements of $A$ tends to infinity.